# Find and replace nth instance of text string using python or bash

Tags: python, bash, sed

I have a configuration file that I am trying to edit.

For example the file says : `listen = 1.1.1.1` and I want it to say `listen = 2.2.2.2`.

However the word `listen` occurs in other places in the file. So I want to know how to read in the file and only change the nth instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "listen = 1.1.1.1" appears on its own line, to change the 4th instance:

```
awk -v n=4 '/listen = / && ++m == n {$3 = "2.2.2.2"} 1' file > file.changed
```